# How to use the rmtree() to delete folders and files

Tags: python

I am trying to delete folders and files within this path: 'Users/ryanunderwood/Desktop'

Here is my code:

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree('Users/ryanunderwood/Desktop')
```

However, this error is being thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ryanunderwood/Documents/Python files/wipeComputer.py", line 10, in <module>
    shutil.rmtree('Users/ryanunderwood/Desktop')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 516, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 377, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.scandir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 374, in _rmtree_unsafe
    with os.scandir(path) as scandir_it:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Users/ryanunderwood/Desktop'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: try absolute path, and check again, something like this : "c:/Users/ryanunderwood/..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of paths: local and absolute paths.

A local path (like you're currently using) is a list of of folders, and will be interpreted as starting in the current working folder. Because of that, the result will depend on where/how you're running you're programm (the working dictionary).
If the folder where you're running python contained a folder 'Foo', `shutil.rmtree('Foo')` would actually work.

However, that's probably not what you want here. If you always want to target the same folder, use an absolute path, which starts with the drive specification (`'C:'` in this case) and contains the whole list of nested folders until you reach your target. 
In this case `"C:/Users/ryanunderwood/Desktop"`, assuming you have the standard folder structure of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying the whole Path to your desktop directory correctly. Probably it's something like `shutil.rmtree("C:/Users/ryanunderwood/Desktop")` depending on on what drive/partition your Desktop folder resides.